# Bind pause and suspend to the same key

Tags: autohotkey

In AHK I can assign pause and suspend to different buttons:

```
 ^F4::
 pause
 return

 ^F5::
 suspend
 return
```

But events don't fire if assigned to the same key. How to bind both `pause` and `suspend` to the same hotkey?

Answer (score 2):

"Suspend must be the first line of the hotkey."

Also, you can write `^F8::pause` in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Add arguments

```
^F8::
Suspend
Pause,,1
return
```